# Discord.js TypeError [InvalidType]: Supplied options is not an object

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I want to code a Music Bot for discord.
[But when  I try to run the Bot, i get this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hw2bw.png)

How can I fix this?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It is an error saying that you are not passing an object on init.

Answer (score 0):

BaseClient expects an object in its constructor and has a default value of `{}`

https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js/blob/main/packages/discord.js/src/client/BaseClient.js#L14

Somewhere on your code (either directly or indirectly, hard to know without seeing the code) you are calling `new BaseClient()` and passing a parameter that is not an object => `new BaseClient(param)`.

If that is not enough to find the issue please provider a snippet of the code where you interact with `discord.js` lib.

Comment: Here is my Code https://imgur.com/a/An0tqau